# How do I do arithmetic with values from two columns with different criteria and then combining the answers, all in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the total of two fields with a specific date criteria, this must be displayed as `Chronic_Load`.

Then I want to do a similar calculation, but with a different date criteria which must be displayed as `Acute_Load`.

Then I would like to have a third calculation where `Chronic_Load` is divided by `Acute_Load`, i.e. the two values from the first two calculations.

Calculation One:

```
SELECT sum((rpe * duration)*1) AS "Acute_Load" FROM users_data where date between adddate(now(),-7) and now()
```

Calculation Two:

```
SELECT sum((rpe * duration)*1.5) AS "Chronic_Load" FROM users_data where date between adddate(now(),-28) and now()
```

Calculation Three:

```
SELECT sum(Acute_Load / Chronic_Load) AS "ACWD"
```

How do combine all of this with the two different criteria in?

Comment: I assume the "date criteria" refers to the `WHERE` clause? These aren't different between the two queries though.

Comment: @sticky bit sorry I corrected it, the one is -7 and the other -28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the "wider" restriction in the `WHERE` clause. For the "narrower" use a `CASE` that puts out zero, if the date isn't in range.

```
SELECT sum(CASE
             WHEN date BETWEEN adddate(now(), -7) AND now() THEN
               rpe * duration
             ELSE
               0
           END) "Acute_Load",
       sum(rpe * duration * 1.5) "Chronic_Load",
       sum(CASE
             WHEN date BETWEEN adddate(now(), -7) AND now() THEN
               rpe * duration
             ELSE
               0
           END) / sum(rpe * duration * 1.5) "ACWD"
       FROM users_data
       WHERE date BETWEEN adddate(now(), -28) and now();
```

Comment: I am getting:
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') / sum(rpe * duration *1.5) AS "ACWD"
       FROM users_data
       WHERE dat' at line 12

Comment: @Seef: Forgot the second `ELSE` branch. See the edit.

Comment: Perfect! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this more succinctly.  The following assumes that `date` is indeed a date and never in the future:

```
select sum(case when date >= current_date - interval 7 day
                then rpe * duration
           end) as Acute_Load,
       sum(rpe * duration * 1.5) as Chronic_Load,
       ( sum(case when date >= current_date - interval 7 day
                  then rpe * duration
             end) /
         sum(rpe * duration * 1.5) 
       ) as acwd
from users_data
where date >= current_date - interval 28 day;
```

Note the changes:

- **date** comparisons should use `date`s, not `datetime`s.
- The `else` clause is unnecessary on aggregations.  They ignore `NULL` values.
- The column aliases do not need to be escaped, so the escape characters just clutter the query.
- Interval arithmetic is clearer than `adddate()`, in my opinion.  It is also more general, working for any time unit.